# UIImageView display distorted image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, imagemagick

I use "ImageMagick" to distort my image on different points. In my example, I only changed the bottom right point. The image distortion works fine but I don't know, how to display the distorted image correct.

As you can see here, the image has a little distortion in the bottom right corner. But you can also see, that the image isn't displayed correct. You can't see the bottom right corner, because the image view cuts the image. Like "overflow: hidden" from css. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try changing the contentMode as AspectFit or AspectFill as you need it

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: whats the problem exactly is the image resized in the imageview?

Comment: I'am sorry, it was my fault. When I distort the image with ImageMagick, ImageMagick cuts the image wrong, not the image view. I open a new question for the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I'am sorry, it was my fault. When I distort the image with ImageMagick, ImageMagick cuts the image wrong, not the image view. I open a new question for the problem. Thanks for your help!